# Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Tengo que realizar un procedimiento con el uso de una transaccion, el procedimiento debe ser que el precio de salida de un libro tenga un descuento del 15% y al final el resultado este en un campo de la tabla Libro

```
    create database libreria;
    use libreria;

    create table Libro(
    LibroID char(8) primary key,
    Titulo  varchar(30) not null,
    Editorial   varchar(20) not null,
    Seccion varchar(25) not null,
    FechaPublicacion    date    null,
    FechaEdicion    date    null,
    PrecioEntrada   float(4)    null,
    PrecioSalida    float(4)    null,
    EstadoLibroID   char(8) not null,
    Vendido  int(1)  not null);

    INSERT INTO Libro(LibroID, Titulo, Editorial, Seccion, PrecioEntrada, PrecioSalida, EstadoLibroID, Vendido) VALUES
    ("LIBRO001", "ERAGON", "ROCA EDITORIAL", "SAGAS FANTASTICAS", "239", "285", "EDOLIB04", "1"),
    ("LIBRO002", "ERAGON", "ROCA EDITORIAL", "SAGAS FANTASTICAS", "239", "285", "EDOLIB04", "0"),
    ("LIBRO003", "CODIGO DA VINCI", "UMBRIEL", "NOVELA POLICIACA", "210", "250", "EDOLIB03", "1"),
    ("LIBRO004", "CODIGO DA VINCI", "UMBRIEL", "NOVELA POLICIACA", "210", "250", "EDOLIB03", "1"),
    ("LIBRO005", "CODIGO DA VINCI", "UMBRIEL", "NOVELA POLICIACA", "210", "250", "EDOLIB03", "0");




ALTER TABLE Libro ADD TotalPrecioDesc float after PrecioSalida;
use Libreria;
drop procedure if exists proceso_libro;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE proceso_libro()
start transaction;
BEGIN
    declare @PrecioDesc float;
    update Libro set TotalPrecioDesc = (select PrecioSalida - (select PrecioDesc=PrecioSalida * 0.15 where LibroID=LibroID)) where LibroID=LibroID;
    if @@error != 0 then
    rollback transaction;
    else 
    commit transaction;
END 
//
DELIMITER ;

CALL proceso_libro;
```

Al igual si se presenta un error al realizar la operacion, debe de ejecutarse un rollback, sino se ejecuta correctamente, debe hacerse un commit
Me marca error de sintaxis, y ya le he buscado, movido, cambiado, agregado y eliminado varias cosas que eran innecesarias porque tenia declarado mas variables y al final me marca este error:

```
Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare @PrecioDesc float;  update Libro set TotalPrecioDesc = (select PrecioSal' at line 2
```

Comment: Es sql-Server o Mysql?

Comment: @EdgarVazquez por el mensaje de error es MySQL

Comment: Si eso veo, pero tampoco dice nada el op